# Excel: Delete words in the beginning and in the end

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to fish out the names of some companies from the strings in the table.

Each string begins with 2 words (that need to be deleted) and ends up with various number of words/characters.

I have tried the following formula, in order to delete the first 2 words:

```
=MID(A6,1+FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A6," ","~",2)),255)
```

But I cannot understand how to remove the last words/characters.

Here is the example:

[image]

In column A is the original text. Column B is the result (how it should look like).

Maybe there is an easier/better way to solve it with VBA?

@Ron Rosenfeld:

[image]

Comment: It's tough to see that screenshot. Based on your example, you want to stop at the first open parenthesis? Would a rule like that work for all your data? Not sure if that first row would be okay with this type of rule.

Comment: @Isolated doesn't look like the first ( would work since (Beijing) is still there in the first example. Maybe (XX) or drop first two and last two "words"?

Comment: @Sam without a definition of the criteria of where you want to cut off the string,  an answer to this will be guesswork.   Please add the criteria to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to

- remove the first two words
- remove the last two substrings where the substrings defined as being set off by parentheses.

If that is the case, try:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),2))+1,999),FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),2))+1,999),"(",CHAR(1),LEN(MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),2))+1,999))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),2))+1,999),"(",""))-1))-1))
```

If you prefer a UDF to implement that same algorithm, I suggest regular expressions:

```
Option Explicit
Function extrCompany(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object
    Const sPat As String = "^(?:\w+\s+){2}(.*?)\s*\([^)]+\)\s*\([^)]+\)[^)(]*$"
    
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = sPat
    extrCompany = .Replace(S, "$1")
End With

End Function
```

Comment: Dear Ron, thank you so much! The formula is perfect and does what it should!

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot implement the function. When I enter it in the VBA, it just doesn't work. Did I miss something?

Comment: When I enter the code into the module and press the RUN button, I see only the empty window for macros. I will add the screenshot to the original post.

Comment: @Sam Thank you for the clear explanation. Your issue is because this is a `Function`, not a `Macro`.  You could call it by entering, for example, on a worksheet (or even in a VBA macro) `=extrCompany(cell_ref)`, or `=extrCompany("string")` where `cell_ref` is the cell containing the string (or `"string"` is the actual string as quoted text)

Comment: Dear Ron, you saved my day! And I have learnt something new - how to implement functions! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the criteria for the right side cutoff is so here is two ways.

This one is assuming there's always a country code (XX):

```
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim strarr() As String
    Dim j As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change this to your sheet name
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lr
            strarr = Split(.Cells(i, 1).Value, " ")
            For j = 2 To UBound(strarr)
                If strarr(j) Like "(??)" Then
                    Exit For
                Else
                    .Cells(i, 2).Value = .Cells(i, 2).Value & " " & strarr(j)
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
```

This next one is basically the same thing except it assumes you want to drop the last two elements of the array.

```
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim strarr() As String
    Dim j As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change this to your sheet name
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lr
            strarr = Split(.Cells(i, 1).Value, " ")
            For j = 2 To UBound(strarr) - 2
                .Cells(i, 2).Value = .Cells(i, 2).Value & " " & strarr(j)
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your cutoff is the first occurrence where you have an apparent country code such as (CN) and every item will have that country code format, then this formula will work. It will check the length between the first open and close parenthesis. If length = 3, then it cuts off 1 character before the open parenthesis, else it cuts after the first closed parenthesis.

```
    =IF(FIND(")",MID(A2,1+FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","~",2)),255)) - FIND("(",MID(A2,1+FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","~",2)),255)) = 3,LEFT(MID(A2,1+FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","~",2)),255),FIND("(",MID(A2,1+FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","~",2)),255))-1),LEFT(MID(A2,1+FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","~",2)),255),FIND(")",MID(A2,1+FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","~",2)),255))))
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately, I receive an error message "There is a problem with a formula" and this part gets highlighted [",MID] (without square brackets, for sure)

Comment: Works on my pc, so not sure why it's not working on yours. You could try splitting this into 2 steps. Column B could be your first formula where you strip off the first 2 words. Then column C could the the formula I used, but replace every instance of your formula with the column B cell reference, and also point the references from column A to column B.

Comment: Dear Isolated, thank you very much! Since my Excel is in German, some commas have to be changed to semicolons :-)